# Create a array in mvel expression and check if variable exists in array

Tags: java, regex, expression, mvel

I have a variable having some numeric value `x = 5;`.

I want to right an expression like:

`if arr = [4,7,10]` contains `x` in **mvel**.

Is that possible, if yes, how ?

As of now I will have to right expression as :

```
x == 4 || x == 7 || x == 10
```

but since i may have a big list can this be made something like

```
x in [4,7,10,...]
```

Code :

```
for(Rule rule: ruleList)
{
    String expresssion = rule.getConditionExpression();
    boolean result = (Boolean) expressionHandler.execute(expresssion,ruleEvalData);

}
```

Here expression will be like :

expression = 'x == 4 || x == 7 || x == 10';

and ruleEvalData will have x in it.

I want to know if

expression ='x in [4,7,10,...]' is possible in **MVEL ?**

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the MVEL `contains` operator. You can construct the list of values to test against using the [literal List](http://mvel.documentnode.com/#lists) syntax.

```
[4,7,10] contains x
```

Oddly enough, I can't find documentation of the `contains` operator in MVEL's documention page, but it [exists in the code](https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mvel2/util/ParseTools.java#L679) and calls the standard [Collection.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.stream.IntStream` class:

```
int[] array = {4, 7, 10};
boolean exist = IntStream.of(array).anyMatch(x -> x == 5);
```

This will return `true` if any elements of this stream `of(array)` match the provided predicate, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Hi, My main query is can i define this int[] array in mvel expression?
Also I dont need to pass x here as it is a variable from my java code and will be populated at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you can use any value instead of literal `5`.

Comment: But you can not declare int[] array in expression itself

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
Integer[] array = {4, 7, 10};
boolean exist = Arrays.asList(array).contains(5);
```